# How to automatically enter a traders name after entering their trader number in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Am doing a simple database for daily sales of a list of traders. The daily sales are recorded by trader number. I would like to be able to enter trader number in one column and then have the traders name automatically entered in next column. Is this possible please?

Comment: Yes it's possible,,, you need to work with LOOKUP formula,,, create additional Table anywhere on Sheet or in another Sheet,, have two columns only Trader ID & Name,,, in Table for Database next to column entering IDs write LOOKUP formula !!

Answer (score 1):

You may use **VLOOKUP** function.

Here is a simple sample.
[image]